# Fragile commands in 2021

Tags: macros, fragile

Since 2015, `\(` `\)`, `\begin{math}` etc. have been made robust. Aside from user-generated commands not created with `\DeclareRobustCommand` and out-of-date packages, are fragile commands still a thing in LaTeX these days? In other words, can I delete that section from my book for LaTeX users (not programmers)? (Discussing this in a later book for people *programming* LaTeX is a whole other thing.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well not completely gone, but you have to try a lot harder to find a case, and if it's a really plausible case quite possibly we'd accept an enhancement request to make the command robust.

For example `\begin` has been robust (only since 2019, not 2015) so `\begin{tabular}` is robust, as is `\\`  (from 2015)  but `\cline` is not, compare these two `\typeout`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\typeout{
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a&b\\
    \cline{1-1}
   c&d
  \end{tabular}}

\typeout{
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a&b\\
    \protect\cline{1-1}
   c&d
  \end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

producing

```
 \begin {tabular}{cc} a&b\\ \omit \@multicnt 1\advance \@multicnt \m@ne \relax 
\def \iterate {}\iterate \let \iterate \relax \@multicnt 1\advance \@multicnt -
1\advance \@multicnt \@ne \relax \def \iterate {}\iterate \let \iterate \relax 
\leaders \hrule height\arrayrulewidth \hfill \cr \noalign {\vskip -\arrayrulewi
dth } c&d \end {tabular}
```

and

```
 \begin {tabular}{cc} a&b\\ \cline{1-1} c&d \end {tabular}
```

Of course `\typeout` here could be replaced by any command with moving argument such as caption or section hesdings.

Comment: Is there any reason why `\cline` hasn't been made robust?

Comment: And I will add, that LaTeX's robustness strategy has broken my old-school debugging strategies for LaTeX. I used to use `\texttt{\meaning\foo}` liberally to see what the current definition of macros was in troublesome documents and now a lot of those troublesome macros won't talk to me.

Comment: @DonHosek that's why we added `\ShowCommand`  :-)

Comment: @DonHosek no no reason I just found it by reverse engineering an example by flicking through latex.ltx looking for a plausible combination. actually there is a possible reason ( `\protect\cline<space>` won't work if `\protect` is `\relax` as it will mess up the `\halign` `\omit`.  Internally it could be made robust in other ways though...

Comment: Another example: `~` is expandable, it expands to `\nobreakspace{}` where `\nobreakspace` is robust -- although this is intentional according to texdoc source2e.

Answer (score 6):

There are still a number of kernel commands that have not been touched for one or the other reason but as David said, for most of them it is difficult to construct meaningful use cases where robustness matters in real life.

The situation is different though for major packages, e.g., amsmath, where many commands are still fragile but shouldn't really. But cleaning that up is rather difficult and the loose ends ended up as a task with rather low priority.

The current status can be found in the test file for github issues 123, e.g.
[amsmath robustness status](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/main/required/amsmath/testfiles/github-amsrobust-0123.tlg) and
[base LaTeX robustness status](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/main/base/testfiles/github-robust-0123.tlg) for those interested in the nitty gritty details. (You may have to also read the corresponding input file (`.lvt`) to make sense of some of the output).

Comment: Ooh, the AMS math stuff is a challenge since I'm covering a lot of "extended" stuff as part of the core material. I can still delete my fragile commands section, I think, but I will need to add a sidebar to cover the symbols that are dangerous.